# PHP SQL Error for INSERT FUNCTION

Tags: php, mysql

I am using using `INSERT` function in `PHP` to insert data into a table. 
Here's the code given below:
Note, when I execute the code, i get an **error**:

> Error: INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) VALUES​​ ('222') You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES​​ ('222')' at
>   line 1

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $passwords = "";
    $dbname = "cmg_log";

    //open connection
    $con = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $passwords, $dbname);
    if (!$con){
        die("Connection fail. ".mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    //insert into database
    $query="INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) VALUES​​ ('222')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $query)){
        echo "Successful";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error: " .$query ."<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Query looks ok, try to remove quotes from values? also share what is field type?

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like case sensitive error, Just use lower case for `values`

```
 $query="INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) values ('222')";
```

Error is annoying but i tried your code and get same error, after replace to lower it works

Answer (score 0):

Update your query & try this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO tbl_test (`name`) VALUES​​ ('222')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query =($con,"INSERT INTO table_name (name)
        VALUES ('222')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var_data = '222';
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) VALUES('$var_data')";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        echo 'success'; exit();
    } else {
        echo 'Connection Error'; exit();
    }
```

Depending on the config / mysql, you might need to change '222' into a var before you insert it. My older server did this to me and i still don't know why. That is the only time i have seen that happen.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are some hidden characters in your query after 'VALUES' keyword.  The reason changing to lower case 'values' work is because you have deleted the hidden characters.

Here is what's actually in your code when I pasted into vim.
`INSERT INTO tbl_test (name) VALUES<200b><200b> ('222')`

You can also see the hidden characters if you use the browser inspect tool to look at that section of the code on this page.

Answer (score -2):

Or you can use below query

```
$query="INSERT INTO tbl_test SET name='abc'";
```

For update query only you to replace `INSERT INTO` with `UPDATE`